# py2neo update node in graph

Tags: database, graph, py2neo

i started using the py2neo database system with django.
How can i update a node in the graph database ?

I created a node:

```
   user = graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node("users_email_single", email, email,
        {"user_id":user_id, 
         "basic_name_firstname": firstname,
         "basic_name_lastname": lastname,
         "contactprivate_email": email,
        })
```

I get the node with following code:

```
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
user = graph_db.get_indexed_node("users_user_id", user_id, user_id)
```

Regards

Comment: I got it. I use the writer batch class to update the properties with the set_propertie function

Comment: set_property is correct beacuse set_node_property is deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also set individual properties outside a batch as follows:

```
user["name"] = "Bob"
user["age"] = 77
```